# getting error while using lua with nginx

Tags: nginx, lua

I am very new to nginx and lua .i have installed Openresty .
below is my code in nginx.conf file .

```
server{
      location /hellolua {
      default_type 'text/plain';
        content_by_lua '        local name = ngx.var.arg_name or "Anonymous"
        ngx.say("Hello, ", name, "!")    ';
        }
       }
```

When i am running

```
sudo service nginx start
```

i am getting error

```
Starting nginx: nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "content_by_lua" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:24
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failedt
```

Please let me know what i am missing .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to me, as if you haven't installed the right module? ngx_lua (http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule)

You mention OpenResty. Did you configure it with lua? If not, the guide is here(http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule#Installation).
Quick resumé:

> The ngx_openresty bundle can be used to install Nginx, ngx_lua, either one of the standard Lua 5.1 interpreter or LuaJIT 2.0, as well as a package of powerful companion Nginx modules. The basic installation step is a simple `./configure --with-luajit && make && make install.`

You can manually compile ngx_lua into nginx too, the full guide is in the link too.

After comment-discussing - I removed the irrelevant part of the answer.

Comment: Double quotes and single quotes are semantically equivalent in Lua: if you start a string with `"` you must end it with `"` and use `'` inside it with no additional escaping, or you can do vice versa.

Comment: Which is exactly what I've done ;-)
I'm just following the documentation, to avoid things like nginx not wanting single-quotes. Haven't worked much with nginx.

Comment: This is the issue i am not able to configure openresty with lua. i am not able to find path where lua is installed.please help me how can i configure i am so confused

Comment: The problem is most likely, Lua simply isn't installed.

Comment: @FrederikSpang lua is installed but i am not able to configure with nginx

Comment: Make sure the ngx_lua module is installed then!

Answer (score 4):

By default, OpenResty's nginx is installed into the path `/usr/local/openresty/nginx/sbin/nginx`. Your system's default nginx init configurations need an update to point to the right locations.